# Regular expression check allowing character input

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

Im doing data validations using a remote for a Farm model and checking the province code I keep getting an error that doesn't accept two characters in.I need the province code to be 2 letters long and to check if they are actually letters. Heres the code for the RemoteController:

```
public JsonResult provinceCodeCheck(string provinceCode)
{
    Regex justLetters = new Regex("^[A-Z]$");
    provinceCode.ToUpper();
    var provinceCodes = db.provinces.Find(provinceCode);

    if (provinceCode.Length != 2)
    {
        return Json("The Province must be 2 letters long",
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else if (!justLetters.Equals(provinceCode))
    {
        return Json("The Province is not letters",
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else if (provinceCodes == null)
    {
        return Json("The Province is not supported, sorry for the         inconvenience",
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }          
}
```

Comment: What you mean it doesn't let you put any letters in? That makes it sound like an issue with your view

Comment: Sorry it lets me put letters in but it fails the check. Ill fix that in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

1. `provinceCode.ToUpper()` doesn't alter the value of `provinceCode`. You'll need to assign it `provinceCode = provinceCode.ToUpper()`
2. `!justLetters.Equals(provinceCode)` is checking whether the `Regex` is equal to the string `provinceCode`. You need to use [Regex.IsMatch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

   ```
   if (!justLetters.IsMatch(provinceCode))
   ```
3. Lastly (thanks to Carnivorus here) your `Regex` is only looking for one upper case letter. If you alter your Regex you can combine the first two if statements into one:

   ```
   var justLetters = new Regex("^[A-Z]{2}$");
   ```

Just as a general little improvement for your code too, you don't need to be using `elseif` here as you're returning inside the `if` statements anyway.

Comment: And the regex is matching exactly one upper case character.

Comment: and 3. Carnivorus's answer

Comment: Agreed @juharr and hometoast

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize i forgot to the assigning of .toUpper() to provinceCode,

Comment: Well the OP can not combine the `if` statements if they want different messages for the wrong length and the characters not being alpha.

Comment: @juharr True...but you could always embed that check if the regex fails right?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex here,linq is your friend:

```
if(provinceCode.All(x=> Char.IsLetter(x))
{
   // valid
}
```

or:

```
if(provinceCode.Length!=2 && provinceCode.Any(x=> !Char.IsLetter(x))
{
   // not valid
}
```

Comment: Even better. Regex is probably slower than a simple check of length and if both characters are upper.

Answer (score 4):

Your RegEx only looks for 1 uppercased letter. You need to use `^[A-Z]{2}$` for exactly 2 uppercase letters

Comment: I've referenced your answer as part of mine so +1

Answer (score 1):

```
 provinceCode = provinceCode.ToUpper();
```

ToUpper() doesn't change the current value, it *returns* the ToUpper'd value

Comment: would that be not allowing the regular expression to pass?